Cable harness plan design question about dimension representation
Maybe this isn't realy a 100% electronic question.
I need to send a drawing of a cable harness to a subcontractor.
My problem is that my predecessor represent the dimensions like this:

And I'm pretty sure that we are supposed to represent the dimensions like this :


If you guys know the standard that precise that it would be amazing.

Is there some reason you can't ask the subcontractor which one they prefer?

Is the connector type & dimensions called out someplace else?  If so, then then the two ways of dimensioning the cable should have the same results.

@DaveTweed Sure I can ask them. I just remember that in my technical drawing class (about 15y ago) you place the dimensions at the ends of the objects.
